# Field Constructors - Get Form Constraints with Repeating Elements

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.1

My ultimate goal is to append * to every label where the associated field is mandatory.

The problem is that within the `FieldElements.constraints` there are no constraints if I have a list of elements.

Here is a code sample showing form with a list of addresses:

```
object Forms {

  val testForm: Form[TestForm] = Form {

    val address = mapping(
      "addressLine" -> nonEmptyText,
      "city"        -> nonEmptyText,
      "country"     -> nonEmptyText.verifying(nonEmpty)
    )(Address.apply _)(Address.unapply)

    // to form mapping for TestForm  
    mapping(

      "mand_string" -> nonEmptyText,
      "non_mand_string" -> optional(text),

      "address_history" -> list(address) // repeated values are allowed for addresses

    )( TestForm.apply _ )( TestForm.unapply )
  }

}
```

Here is the field constructor logic to add *s to mandatory fields:

```
object MyHelpers {

  implicit val myFields = FieldConstructor( fieldElem => {

    Logger.debug( "Label = " + fieldElem.label )
    Logger.debug( "Constraints = " + fieldElem.field.constraints )

    val new_elem = fieldElem.copy( args = appendAsteriskToMandatoryFields(fieldElem) )

    views.html.fs1(new_elem)

  })

  /** Adds a * to the end of a label if the field is mandatory
   * 
   */
  private def appendAsteriskToMandatoryFields(fieldElem: FieldElements): Map[Symbol,Any] = {

    fieldElem.args.map{ case(symbol, any) => 

      if(symbol == '_label && isRequiredField(fieldElem)){ 
        (symbol, any + "*")
      } else { 
        symbol -> any 
      }

    }

  }

  /** Does this element have the constraint that it is required?
   * 
   */
  private def isRequiredField(fieldElem: FieldElements): Boolean = {

    fieldElem.field.constraints.exists{case(key, _) => key == "constraint.required"}

  }

}
```

I expect to see *s appended to all form elements except `non_mand_string` but here is the resulting page: http://s29.postimg.org/5kb5u2hjb/Screen_Shot_2014_08_05_at_1_49_17_PM.png

Only `man_string` has a * appended. None of the address fields have *s as expected.

Here is the output of the logs:

```
[debug] application - Label = Mandatory String
[debug] application - Constraints = List((constraint.required,WrappedArray()))
[debug] application - Label = Non-Mandatory String
[debug] application - Constraints = List()
[debug] application - Label = Address Line
[debug] application - Constraints = List()
[debug] application - Label = City
[debug] application - Constraints = List()
[debug] application - Label = Country
[debug] application - Constraints = List()
```

Is it possible to assign these constraints so I don't have to manually add *s to every list instance in my application?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this problem today: I'm using @repeat helper and I've found the constraints being tied to the single repeated field's name (i.e. "field_name") instead of each repeated field (i.e. "field_name[0]")

The solution I've found so far is just to rebuild the field, using the right constraints.

```
@repeat(theForm("repeated_field")) { field =>
            @myInputNumber(
                Field(
                    form = theForm, name = "name", 
                    constraints = theForm.constraints.find(_._1 == "repeated_field").get._2,
                    format = field("field_name").format,
                    errors = field("field_name").errors,
                    value = field("field_name").value
                ))
    }
```

Of course this code is just an example, you should probably check for empty Constraints or existing ones.

Hope to be helpful,
Pietro